# rewrite for .htaccss with mobile site

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm needing help with setting up the rewrite rules for my site.

I have one rule set up so it adds www. to my site, but I also have a mobile site that starts with m. and don't know what to put in the `RewriteCond` I'm not sure if there is a IF type statment...

What I currently have is...

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website\.us$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !m\.website\.us$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.us/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m)\.website\.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.us/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can see how the pipe works as an OR. Right now I'm getting a redirect issue with no .htaccess redirect so I have to figure out whats causing the problem then I'll report back if the new rule will work.

Comment: Ok, that worked out great. I'm guessing I can add `(www|cdn|dev|m)` as I want correct?